# Question about electric field singularities

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, singularities

I was reading the first chapter of Purcell-Morin (3rd Edition) and came across an explanation of what a singularity is.

It said that a singularity of the field isn't necessarily a point where E$\rightarrow \infty$ but also any place where the field changes magnitude or direction discontinuous (like "an infinitesimal thin layer of concentrated charge").

I'd like like to ask a question. Let's talk about the case of a spherical shell with radius R which has charge only on its surface. Since charge inside it is zero and just outside it, there is some charge, if we go from r < R to r just slightly than R, the electric field would suddenly change. So is the surface of that shell also a singularity?

Comment: It is according to that definition

Comment: @Wolphramjonny: That should be an answer.